# CodeIgniter Dynamic rows from JavaScript table entries

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to grab my post data from my view and have it there on page reload (after it passes through validation), I am really struggling with this as I am only just learning JavaScript so anything dynamic to my is completely new...

What the data looks like in a print_R():

```
Array ( [firstname] => [lastname] => [address1] => [address2] => [addressSuburb] => [addressState] => [addressPostcode] => [email] => [addressCountry] => AU [orderRef] => [orderNote] => [orderTrack] => [counter0] => 0 [itemCode0] => 1234 [Desc0] => Test1 [Qty0] => 1 [Cost0] => 5 [counter1] => 1 [itemCode1] => 5678 [Desc1] => Test 2 [Qty1] => 2 [Cost1] => 10 [create] => Create Order )
```

What my current view loops look like:

```
                <?php if($this->input->post()):?>
                <?php foreach($this->input->post('counter') as $counter): ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach($this->input->post() + $counter AS $key => $value): ?>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key + $counter ?>" value="<?php echo $value ?>"/>
                    </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

The Error I am getting:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I assume its because counter isnt actually an array, just part of it... I dont know how to output each line of entry data into its own array, then it would actually be rather easy to do...

Please don't give me a hard time for having it all in the view, as I am learning heaps easier to have it centralized there while trying to get an output.

Comment: I would suggest putting your post values into arrays in the controller and pre format them. Currently this will include your counter post var on the inner foreach. Also the + counter doesn't make sense, it is going to add the $counter var to the post array, read up on array_merge vs + in PHP. What is in the $counter post var? I assume just a number.

Comment: Basically it would be nice to have each line come up as its own array in the post data but I cannot find a way that works when using JS to create the rows. The counter post is just an INT output of table.rows.length

Comment: Why are you adding the counter to the post array in the inner foreach?